# On the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equations

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

Goldstein's Classical Mechanics proposes two ways to derive the Euler-Lagrange (E-L) equations. One is by the D'Alembert's Principle of virtual work and the second is by Hamilton's Principle of Least Action. They are both motivated quite differently.

The D'Alembert's principle is one that tries getting rid of the constraint forces by considering 'virtual displacements' -- for whom the work done by constraint forces is zero. He then procedes to change coordinates to a linearly independent set using the holonomic equations of constraint, which leads us to the E-L equations.

Hamilton's principle is motivated quite differently. It looks at all possible paths in configuration space and picks the one in which the action is extremised. This, too, leads to the E-L equations.

I wanted to know how/if the two methods are equivalent. As in, how does using virtual displacements and changing variables equate to extremizing a functional of a Lagrangian?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131363/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/344720/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks for pointing these out. I had noticed and read through the possible duplicates before. I felt the answers didn’t satisfy my confusion, and hence I tried rewording the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maupertuis, who discovered the priciple of least action, took the point of view that the quite miraculous coincidence of the virtual work equations with  those coming from  least action  was a proof that we exist in the best of all possible worlds ---- and that this implies  the existence of God.  Voltaire wrote *Candide* to refute  this type of argument.

My own view is that the two derivations are logically distinct within classical mechanics, but that their  coincidence is a consequence of the Feynman path integral in quantum mechanics. Least action is the stationary phase  approximation to the path integral, and Newton's equations (equivalent to D'Alembert) follow from Ehrenfest's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question has been closed I have repurposed the answer for another question about the nature of Hamilton's stationary action.

The title of that other question is:
[Is there a "geometrical" reason for the principle of stationary action?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/575755/is-there-a-geometrical-reason-for-the-principle-of-stationary-action/580535#580535)

I can confirm that the two methods are equivalent.

The two have the following in common: the work-energy theorem.

To explain how the work-energy theorem is at play I need to set up some things first.

- When the force is a *conservative force* ability to do work and potential energy are the same. From here on I will refer only to 'kinetic energy' and 'potential energy'
- Theory of motion is formulated in terms of differential equations, so when I refer to the work-energy theorem it should be understood as the work-energy theorem in differential form.

$$ \frac{dE_k}{dt} = \frac{-dE_p}{dt} $$

- Finally, this discussion will use the following property of integration: When you have a curve and the integral of that curve: when you double the slope of the curve then the value of the integral doubles too. More generally, the rate of change of the *value* of an integral is equal to the rate of change of the curve's *slope*.

The animation below consists of 7 frames, each displayed for three seconds. The 7 frames are screenshots of an interactive diagram.

[image: Hamilton's stationary action]

The case represented in the diagram is a uniform downward force.

To minimize the terms of the equations I have selected the following conditions:
Total duration: 2 seconds (from t=-1 to t=1)
Gravitational acceleration: 2 $m/s^2$
Mass of the object: 1 unit of mass.

With $h(t)$ for height as a function of time:

$$ h(t) = -(t + 1)(t - 1) = -t^2 + 1 $$

The black line represents the trajectory of the object.

The variation has been implemented in the following way:

$$ h(t,p_v) = (1 + p_v)(-t^2 + 1) $$

That is, the trial trajectory is expressed as a function of *two* variables: time and the variational parameter $p_v$

In the diagram the value in the slider at the bottom is the variational parameter $p_v$

In the diagram, in the upper-left quadrant, the black line represents the trial trajectory.

In the upper-right quadrant:
Red graph: kinetic energy
green graph: *minus* potential energy
The horizontal axis is 'time'; the graphs represent functions of time

For the red graph and the green graph, the *slope* of the graph represents the time derivative of the energy.

When the slopes of the red and green graphs are parallel *the entire time* the trial trajectory coincides with the true trajectory.

In the lower-left quadrant:
The slopes of the respective graphs do not change at the same rate. In the space of negative values of the variational parameter the green graph changes faster, and with the variational parameter larger than zero the red graph changes faster.

The diagram in the lower-right quadrant stands out. In the other three quadrants the horizontal axis represents time. In the lower-right quadrant the horizontal axis represents the variational parameter.

Let me introduce action components $S_K$ and $S_P$.
$S_K$ for the kinetic energy component of the action, and $S_P$ for the potential energy component of the action.

In the lower-right quadrant:
red graph: $S_K$
green graph: *minus* $S_P$

In the lower-right quadrant: when the variational parameter is zero the two graphs have the same absolute slope, with opposite sign.

It follows: when the variation parameter is zero:

$$ \frac{dS_k}{dp_v} - \frac{dS_p}{dp_v} =  0   $$

This is Hamilton's stationary action.

This demonstration is for a specific case; uniform acceleration, the reasoning generalizes to all cases. In general the response to variation of the trial trajectory is different for the kinetic and potential energy.

**Energy mechanics**

As stated at the start: the work-energy theory in the form of time derivatives is as follows:

$$ \frac{d(E_k)}{dt} = \frac{d(-E_p)}{dt} $$

However, this form is not practical; potential energy is by nature a function of position, but this form calls for the potential energy's time derivative.

We do need to take a derivative, but we're not confined to taking the time derivative. The obvious choice: we convert the equation to taking the derivative with respect to position.

$$ \frac{d(E_k)}{ds} = \frac{d(-E_p)}{ds} $$

I propose to name the above equation 'the energy equation'.

the term $ \frac{d(E_k)}{ds} $ is readily streamlined:

$$ \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{ds} = \tfrac{1}{2}m\left( 2v\frac{dv}{ds} \right) = m\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{dv}{ds} = m\frac{dv}{dt} $$

**Jacob's Lemma**

There is a lemma in variational calculus, first stated by Jacob Bernoulli (In an earlier answer I have proposed to name it 'Jacob's Lemma'.)

When Johann Bernoulli had presented the Brachistochrone problem to the mathematicians of the time Jacob Bernoulli was among the few who solved it. The treatment by Jacob Bernoulli is in the *Acta Eruditorum*, May 1697, pp. 211-217

Jacob opens his treatment with an observation concerning the fact that the curve that is sought is a minimum.

[image: Jacob Bernoulli brachistochrone]

Lemma. Let ACEDB be the desired curve along which a heavy point falls from A to B in the shortest time, and let C and D be two points on it as close together as we like. Then the segment of arc CED is among all segments of arc with C and D as end points the segment that a heavy point falling from A traverses in the shortest time. Indeed, if another segment of arc CFD were traversed in a shorter time, then the point would move along AGFDB in a shorter time than along ACEDB, which is contrary to our supposition.

I assume that Jacob's lemma generalizes to all of variational calculus.

If the curve *as a whole* is an extremum, then every *subsection* is an extremum too, down to infinitisimally short subsections. Hence the condition for a curve that is an *extremum* can also be expressed as a differential equation.

And that is indeed what the Euler-Lagrange equation does. The Euler-Lagrange equation takes a problem stated in terms of variational calculus and restates it in terms of *differential calculus*.

**Hamilton's stationary action**

With the above in place we examine Hamilton's stationary action.

We take Newton's second law, and we derive the work-energy theorem from it.

Hamilton's stationary action takes a problem in mechanics, and uses the work-energy theorem to restate it in terms of variational calculus. Then the Euler-Lagrange equation is used to bring the form of the problem back to differential calculus.

Comment: The work energy-theorem uses Newton and proceeds to least action.   $A=B$, $B=C$ therefore $A=C$;  A mathematical trueism, but one that misses the point:  Why *start* from least (stationary) action? Who ordered that?