# How do quantum fields really couple?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, interactions

The term "coupling" between quantum fields refers to certain terms in the Lagrangian (density) $\mathcal{L}$ where the respective field operators appear together, e.g. $g\phi^\dagger\psi $ with coupling constant $g$.

Knowing the mathematical description/origin of a coupling in QFT, I wonder: How can a quantum field $\phi$ of a certain kind excite a quantum state of another totally unrelated  type of quantum field $\psi$? Is there are more "physical" picture of how the coupling really happens instead of just a mathematical one?

Comment: I can give you a picture, but not from QFT, rather from simple quantum mechanics. The language in which phenomena are described may differ, but the phenomenon is the same. In the de-excitation of an atom, the movement of the electron is coupled with the states of the electromagnetic field. The coupling constant is given by the interaction law between the movement of a charge and the states of the e.m. field.

Comment: When one quantizes the coupling term $g\phi^\dagger\psi$, one obtains the Feynman diagram vertex. Coupling is represented by vertices in Feynman diagrams.

Comment: "Coupling" isn't special to quantum field theory. In *any* kind of mechanics, if one thing pushes on another it shows up as a product in the Lagrangian.

Comment: Sure, but when objects in mechanics hit each other, it is due to the same force (mostly electromagnetic repulsion of the constituents). They couple via the same (EM) field. But how can field A excite field B? Maybe there is no satisfying physical picture...

Comment: @quantumorsch likewise in classical mechanics you could ask why do they couple via the EM field. And if you come up with some other kind of "intermediate" interaction you could ask how do they couple to *that* interaction. The answer to *how* do they couple is the one you gave: through the interaction term in the Lagrangian. But it seems to me that what you are really looking for is more like *why* do they do that? See [this Phys.SE question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90164/58382) about that matter.

Comment: Maybe for us to understand your question you should present your picture of what fields "physically" are and why different fields _shouldn't_ couple.

Answer (score -1):

Well, all the fields exist in the same space, right? So they occupy the same volume. Perhaps the different fields are actually different vibrational mode families of something finer; in that case, coupling isn't surprising, since we're observing different vibrational mode families of the same underlying field. There is probably partial overlap of the frequencies between the mode families, perhaps this is the origin of coupling?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/403220)