# Why does magnet attract and push each other?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

Why do magnet attract and push each other? This question seems easy, but in fact, it is big, maybe as big as trying explaining gravity with quantum physics to the origin that how each particle attracts each other. I mean, we all know the magnetic line of force which attracts each other in opposite direction and propels otherwise. But, that is how they behave. My question is why it behave that way? Why it pushes and attracts each other? Ampere and Faraday explain how by observation, but they do not explain why.

Comment: In general, physics explains how things behave, not why they behave that way. “Why?” is more for philosophers and theologians (who seldom understand the “How?”, so be skeptical about their answers). Physicists can easily imagine universes with very different laws of physics.

Comment: Why start with magnetism?  Wouldn't it be bolder to ask why *anything* exists?

Comment: See this question and answers https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90164/

Comment: You may be be better off asking for some specific cause-effect relationship where the effect is magnetism. "Why" questions tend to lead nowhere in physics, because they're more a result of human language habits than of the relationship between facts. This is an interesting question, because it exposes this subtle but important fact about physics, and indeed most of the sciences. Unless you'd be satisfied with any cause, in which case I could name several, if you'd like more information on why this isn't a question that can be answered to your satisfaction, read [this](http://bit.ly/3b2ijxq).

Comment: The comments above are partially right about why questions in physics. Physics describes how the universe behaves, but does not give reasons for that behavior. But sometimes there is a different kind of answer. "Because this behavior is a consequence of some simpler or more obvious behavior." In this case, an answer might say that individual iron atoms are little magnets. Bonds between iron atoms require neighboring atoms to orient so their magnet field align. That might be enough, or you might have to explain why iron atoms are little magnets and why bonds work that way.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I have changed from a existing question to why it attracts problem.

Comment: You could ask the same question about the (simpler?) case of electrostatic forces.